# need dynamic jCarousel to remember position clicked when changing PHP pages

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, jcarousel

(PHP / Javascript coding newbie here)

I have a dynamic script loading contextual images into a list for a jCarousel in a Word Press PHP template.  It rotates automatically and the images link to new pages fine.  example is here:http://www.thelitigator.ca in top right (Contributors).

What I want to do is when the user clicks on an image, a new dynamic page is loaded (a different template in WordPress) and the jCarousel should re-appear with the same list and in the same position as when it was clicked (rather than restart from the beginning again).

I am assuming that I must build an array with the list items and pass a parameter that stores the ID or KEY of the first visible image for the new page to reload. But the coding is complex for me.

I've looked extensively, but am wondering if there is a code sample of this use of jCarousel to learn from out there?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scroll functionality of jcariousel and put it to the session.then on body on load and jcarousel init method you can fetch the session value and update the scroll position

```
  jQuery('#listelements').jcarousel({

//inti call back will scroll on specific session set jcarousel item

                  initCallback : pCarousel.init

});

});

var pCarousel = {

            init : function(carousel) {

//carousel.scroll(n) scrolls to the nth element

                  carousel.scroll(1);

                  return false;

                  });

                }
```